# Adding powershell script to Poststeps folder in App_Data - Is it possible?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to do some post step stuff when Sitecore has been installed/set up (And no post step when solution has been built). And it seems that the poststeps folder in App_Data seems to be the way to go.

How does it work? For instance, when setting up SXA I've noticed this file in the poststeps folder:
*Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Installer.ExperienceAcceleratorWDPInstallationPostStep, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Installer*
I assume it calls for method in assembly Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Installer(similar to a process in pipelines). Is it possible to call a Powershell script instead? Please advice :-)

Comment: https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/sitecore-cleanslate/ & https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/late-to-the-post-step-party/

Comment: Powershell or Sitecore Powershell?

If Sitecore Powershell then there is no issue with it, you can call it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091185/running-a-sitecore-powershell-script-from-code. If Powershell then it is also possible to call it by C# code https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.1. BUT, as C# code will be executed by the ApplicationPoolIdentity, you will not be able to do many things in powershell due to rights restrictions.

Comment: https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/866

Comment: @AlanPłócieniak, so I need to install a package it seems. I'm setting up a site in docker, and would like to do some "pre setup stuff".  Ok great, Thank you all for your comments!!

Comment: Hey @AlanPłócieniak, feel free to answer my question. So I can reward you :-)

Comment: If you are using Docker, would it not be better to create a custom image and do whatever post setup stuff you need in that? You will probably be tearing down/up the instance many many times during development...

Comment: Hey @jammykam. Yes, good point indeed. Thank you 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a neat way to run post steps with **[Sitecore Powershell Extensions](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases)**.

You can invoke it (**SPE** script) after package installation like regular post steps (`Sitecore.Install.Framework.IPostStep` implementations).

Advantages I see over regular post steps:

- no DLL needed (if you are working with **SXA** you already have **SPE** installed ), post step can be executed immediately after packages installation,

  If you deploy items only or just want to invoke post step via
  packages installation you will save one application restart,
- minimalistic configuration - all you need to do is to provide **scriptID** in custom attributes of your package,
- easy to write custom dialogs. For me it is much easier and faster to scaffold new dialog in **SPE** than in `xml`. So if you need to ask about something user and based on the decision make actions, that's the way to go.

**Example configuration**

[image]

You can find current namespace of **ScriptPostStep** [here](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/blob/master/src/Spe/Integrations/Install/ScriptPostStep.cs)

(currently: `Spe.Integrations.Install.ScriptPostStep`)

**Demo:**

[image]